# Creation of an outlook addin <VB.NET, VSTO>

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I have created an outlook add-in using VSTO VB.net. This outlook addin to select the email category (Restricted, Unclassified or Confidential).

Upon selecting the any of these category, it should reflect in the first line of email body which shows whether this email is Restricted/Unclassified or Confidential.

This add-in is working fine when the email body is empty. But when the email body already contains the content and when I select the email category then it is clearing the email body content and write the email category type.

I'm trying to just append the email category type on the first line of the email body and when ever i change the category type it should update accordingly.

Could any one please assist me with some pointers. I'm new to VB.Net and I don't want to post any questions without any trial work. Below is my code.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon

Public Class Ribbon1

Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs)

Dim application As Outlook.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Dim inspector As Outlook.Inspector = application.ActiveInspector
Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML

mailItem.HTMLBody = "<i style=""color:red;""><b>" & "Message : Confidential" & "</b></i>" & mailItem.HTMLBody


End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs)

Dim application As Outlook.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Dim inspector As Outlook.Inspector = application.ActiveInspector
Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)

mailItem.HTMLBody = "<i style=""color:maroon;""><b>" & "Message : Restricted" & "</b></i>" & mailItem.HTMLBody

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs)


Dim application As Outlook.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Dim inspector As Outlook.Inspector = application.ActiveInspector
Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)

mailItem.HTMLBody = "<i style=""color:silver;""><b>" & "Message : Unclassified" & "</b></i>" & mailItem.HTMLBody

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without doing extensive testing, your key issue is that you are placing illegal HTML elements before the `head` and `body` tags - so the correct information cannot be displayed, thus creating a seemingly empty e-mail (or may actually be empty because MS could discard the illegal code).

To help yourself, use `Debug.Print` or `Console.Writeline` and output your existing HTMLBody to your immediate\Output window. There you will see the construct and identify if it already has a `<head>` or `<body>` tag.

From there, you will have to work out how you insert your classification tag into the `<body>` tag. This could be done using the XML tools within VB.NET, or you could construct a fairly complex string parsing function that splits the existing string and inserts your new element in the right place.